# Is it better to use #pragma comment (lib, **) to include libs?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, pragma

I think there are two ways to add libs. 1 is using #pragma comment, another is adding it in the linker option in the project property.

Which one is better?

Comment: What do you mean by *better*? Both approaches allow you to link against a library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Library importing: #pragma comment VS Visual studio project input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287338/library-importing-pragma-comment-vs-visual-studio-project-input)

Comment: Are you compiling the library in VC++ as well?  If so, just make the library a dependent of your project.   Not only will it be recompiled when needed, it will also be linked in without any code/properties changes.