# Cannot open lib unless I manually copy it in my project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, linker

When trying to import an external library from a different drive I keep getting error LNK1104 "cannot open foo.lib"

I set up the correct paths in:

> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories
>
> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories
>
> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
>
> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

And the correct .lib filename including extension in:

> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

This still gives me the error and the only way I have found to fix it is to manually copy the .lib (or .dll) file inside my project, by copying it the linker can find it and link it correctly.

Pretty much all the questions I have found on SO say to set the correct paths and filename of the .lib like I did, why this is not working and I have to directly copy the .lib file inside my project directory to have it work?

Comment: ***I set up the correct paths in*** Your compiler is telling you that you have not set the correct paths. Is there a space in the path?

Comment: @drescherjm there is no space and I have checked like 10 times trying with both relative and absolute paths, manually writing the path and using VS folder explorer

Comment: Maybe one of the other paths before the entry you added in `Additional Include Directories` is not correct.

Comment: I assume you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit and that the .lib you are using is the same file you copied so its definitely not corrupt.

Comment: @drescherjm I checked all the paths again but they are correct, I'm not mixing 32 and 64 bit (I'm using only 64) and the lib I copied is the one in the folder which path I wrote in the properties. Also this is a static library, I don't know if that helps or not since I need to do the same for dynamic libraries too.

Comment: Success if you switch between Debug and Release?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam no the problem persists in both Debug and Release (switching the lib/dll version accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Error LNK1104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=vs-2019), as far as I'm concerned the cause of this issue is that the compiler couldn't search the directory of the .lib file.

To fix a path issue, we should verify that the LIB environment variable is set and contains all the directories for the libraries you use, for every configuration you build. In the IDE, the LIB variable is set by the Library Directories property on the [VC++ Directories Property Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2019).

If the static library is not part of the solution,In the VC++ Directories property page, I suggest you should try to add the path to the directory where the .lib file is located in Library Paths.

For more details ,I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=vs-2019#consuming-static-libraries).

Comment: Yeah that's what I don't understand, everywhere it says to do the steps I have done and it will work but doesn't for me. I'm sure the .lib is not corrupted or something like that because I copy the same one I'm trying to point to in my project folder and it works, I'm pretty sure the paths are correct because I used the VS explorer to find them and I checked them more times than comfortable. It's like my VS is ignoring the ```Library Directories``` values that I select. It does however work for the .h files, is there maybe an option hidden somewhere that overwrites/ignores the Library paths?

Comment: Try to add the code to your source file: "#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")"

Comment: Ok now I'm REALLY confused. I put the pragma in, run the program but forgot to remove the .lib from my project folder so I wasn't sure if it was finding it because it was in the folder like before or thanks to the pragma, I removed the .lib from my folder and it worked. All good, then i removed the pragma and now my linker is linking the file correctly... I don't get it, i didn't change anything in the configuration of the project

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, libname) tells the linker to add the 'libname' library to the list of library dependencies, as if you had added it in the project properties at Linker->Input->Additional dependencies.The linker searches first in the current working directory and then in the path specified in the LIB environment variable.For more details you could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/7f0aews7(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Ok but why does it now work even after removing the ```#pragma```? Also, that shouldn't be needed since the documentation says that it's the same as putting the path to the library in Linker->Input->additional dependencies like I had already done but didn't work. Just trying to understand what was going on in case I find the same error in future projects

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the link:[Library importing: #pragma comment VS Visual studio project input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287338/library-importing-pragma-comment-vs-visual-studio-project-input)