# How to debug unresolved external symbols error in VS when lib is already added to additional dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, linker

I'm using a C++ library that uses functions in wininet.lib.  When I compile in VS2017 I get link errors.

I've added wininet.lib to the project's additional dependencies and made sure it's in the final commandline but still get the linker errors:

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol __imp_InternetOpenW

But everything compiles if I add:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Wininet.lib")
```

To my code.  I have another similar project that compiles fine with the same library without the #pragma.

How can I debug why VS2017 can't find a dependency when the lib is added to the additional dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably added `wininet.lib` only for a specific configuration or platform but built for another combination. Please have a closer look at your project properties. There're two drop down lists in the top most part of the properties dialog.

This would at least explain why the `#pragma` works since it applies regardless of the chosen configuration and platform.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what happens when you try and solve problems at 3:00am.  I sadly assumed that VS would show the properties for the currently selected config in the main UI, alas it remembers the last config you chose in the properties window.  Also good tip about #pragma and configs.

Comment: You're welcome! But I wouldn't go for `#pragmas` all the time. They have their own issues: They don't specify the path of the library and if the library isn't globally available you still have to add the library path manually to the project properties.

Comment: @ Geordie,For more details about `#pragma comment` VS `Visual studio project input`,I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287338/library-importing-pragma-comment-vs-visual-studio-project-input